# Using .split() to break down a String into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to break down a string into an array. This code below does do it, but I now need to break it down into a either a sub array.

Here is the String and the Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var content='Image{BackgroundImage: Image.gif;Position: 0, 0;Width: 320;Height: 480;}Button{BackgroundImage: Button.gif;Position: 49, 80;Width: 216;Height: 71;}Button{BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;Transition: View2;Position: 65, 217;Width: 188;Height: 134;}Label{Position: 106, 91;Width: 96;Height: 34;Text: "Button";FontSize: 32;Color: 0.12549, 0.298039, 0.364706, 1;}';

var result = content.split('}');
result.pop();// removing the last empty element
console.log(result);
for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++)
{
    result[i]+='}';
    console.log(result);
        $('div').append('<li>' + result[i] + '</li>');
}
})
```

This out puts:

```
<li>Image{BackgroundImage: Image.gif;Position: 0, 0;Width: 320;Height: 480;}</li>
<li>Button{BackgroundImage: Button.gif;Position: 49, 80;Width: 216;Height: 71;}</li>
<li>Button{BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;Transition: View2;Position: 65, 217;Width: 188;Height: 134;}</li>
<li>Label{Position: 106, 91;Width: 96;Height: 34;Text: "Button";FontSize: 32;Color: 0.12549, 0.298039, 0.364706, 1;}</li>
```

What I need to do now is break it down even further so that I have the word prior to {} i.e Image for the first one

Ideally I would like the output to be a key/value object like this

```
    {
        "Controls": [{ "Image":"{BackgroundImage: Image.gif;Position: 0, 0;Width: 320;Height: 480;}", 
    "Button":"{BackgroundImage: Image.gif;Position: 0, 0;Width: 320;Height: 480;}", 
"Button":"{BackgroundImage: Image.gif;Position: 0, 0;Width: 320;Height: 480;}", 
    "Label":"{BackgroundImage: Image.gif;Position: 0, 0;Width: 320;Height: 480;}", }],
    }
```

My main goal is to be able to target either Key or the Value at the end of this.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Where's that string coming from? Why that format?

Comment: The String is delivered to me from another program and I need to parse/break it down into something that can be manipulated i.e. Target and modify the 'height' or'x', etc. I used the Split() function to get this far, but dont know how to break it down further while still keeping all the data.

Comment: I suppose the key/val that I asked for would not work as is because of the duplicates of 'Button'. Maybe adding an index to the key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This should produce the output you want:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var content='Image{BackgroundImage: Image.gif;Position: 0, 0;Width: 320;Height: 480;}Button{BackgroundImage: Button.gif;Position: 49, 80;Width: 216;Height: 71;}Button{BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;Transition: View2;Position: 65, 217;Width: 188;Height: 134;}Label{Position: 106, 91;Width: 96;Height: 34;Text: "Button";FontSize: 32;Color: 0.12549, 0.298039, 0.364706, 1;}';

    var result = content.split('}');
    result.pop();// removing the last empty element
    var obj = {Controls:{}};

    $.each(result, function (i, v) {
        var key = v.split('{');
        var value = v.replace(key[0], '') + '}';

        if (key[0] !== 'Button') {
            obj.Controls[key[0]] = value;
        } else {
            if (!obj.Controls.hasOwnProperty('Buttons')) {
                obj.Controls['Buttons'] = [];
            }   
            obj.Controls.Buttons.push(value);
        }
    });

    console.log(obj);
});​
```

**Working Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/fewds/TuNTV/2/

**Output Example:**

```
{
    "Controls": {
        "Image": "{BackgroundImage: Image.gif;Position: 0, 0;Width: 320;Height: 480;}",
        "Buttons": [
            "{BackgroundImage: Button.gif;Position: 49, 80;Width: 216;Height: 71;}",
            "{BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;Transition: View2;Position: 65, 217;Width: 188;Height: 134;}"
        ],
        "Label": "{Position: 106, 91;Width: 96;Height: 34;Text: \"Button\";FontSize: 32;Color: 0.12549, 0.298039, 0.364706, 1;}"
    }
}
```

**If you just want to have multiple key occurrences increment you could use this:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var content='Image{BackgroundImage: Image.gif;Position: 0, 0;Width: 320;Height: 480;}Image{BackgroundImage: Image2.gif;Position: 0, 0;Width: 320;Height: 480;}Button{BackgroundImage: Button.gif;Position: 49, 80;Width: 216;Height: 71;}Button{BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;Transition: View2;Position: 65, 217;Width: 188;Height: 134;}Button{BackgroundImage: Button3.gif;Transition: View2;Position: 65, 217;Width: 188;Height: 134;}Label{Position: 106, 91;Width: 96;Height: 34;Text: "Button";FontSize: 32;Color: 0.12549, 0.298039, 0.364706, 1;}Label{Position: 106, 91;Width: 96;Height: 34;Text: "Button";FontSize: 32;Color: 0.12549, 0.298039, 0.364706, 1;}';

    var result = content.split('}');
    result.pop();// removing the last empty element
    var obj = {Controls:{}};

    function nextProp(key) {
        if(obj.Controls.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var num = key.match(/\d+$/);
            if (num) {
                return nextProp(key.replace(num[0], '') + (parseInt(num[0], 10) + 1));
            } else {
                return nextProp(key + '1');
            }
        }

        return key;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        var key = result[i].split('{');
        var value = result[i].replace(key[0], '') + '}';
        obj.Controls[nextProp(key[0])] = value;
    }

    console.log(obj);
});​
```

**Working Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/fewds/TuNTV/5/

**Output Example:**

```
{
    "Controls": {
        "Image": "{BackgroundImage: Image.gif;Position: 0, 0;Width: 320;Height: 480;}",
        "Image1": "{BackgroundImage: Image2.gif;Position: 0, 0;Width: 320;Height: 480;}",
        "Button": "{BackgroundImage: Button.gif;Position: 49, 80;Width: 216;Height: 71;}",
        "Button1": "{BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;Transition: View2;Position: 65, 217;Width: 188;Height: 134;}",
        "Button2": "{BackgroundImage: Button3.gif;Transition: View2;Position: 65, 217;Width: 188;Height: 134;}",
        "Label": "{Position: 106, 91;Width: 96;Height: 34;Text: \"Button\";FontSize: 32;Color: 0.12549, 0.298039, 0.364706, 1;}",
        "Label1": "{Position: 106, 91;Width: 96;Height: 34;Text: \"Button\";FontSize: 32;Color: 0.12549, 0.298039, 0.364706, 1;}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of nesting the 'Buttons' can we just assign an index to the key i.e. Button[2] or 'Button-2'? The problem is that I would be getting huge strings that could have multiples of control(image, button, etc). The will be times that I may even get a nested items like this scrollview(w:1,x:2,y:3{Button{x:4,y:5,w:6}}. Any assistance in how to go about that would be appreciated

Comment: @Rob I added another example for you, this one will just increment the keys to account for multiple key occurrences.

Comment: This is very helpful. Sorry for the noob question, but how would I target any of these items? i.e. I just want to return 'Image' or if I want to return 'Image:"{all the stuff}"? I tried obj.Button but get undefined. Thanks

Comment: @Rob You can get the first button by calling `obj.Controls.Buttons[0]` in my first example, and in my second example it would be `obj.Controls.Button`

Comment: @Rob Any time, hope this was helpful!

Comment: Is it possible to exclude the numbering and just allow duplicates? Im not sure if that would throw an error having duplicate keys. I tried modifying your code to remove the if() statement and it only returned 1 of each (1 button, 1, image, 1 label. If not possible, could you make a sub item of "index":"1"? Im finding in my program that I need to match the first item(i.e. Button) in find, but the Button1 is throwing it off. Thanks Again

Answer (score 0):

use regexp might be better

```
// the regexp
var re = /(.+?)(\{.*?\})/g,
    group;

var content='Image{BackgroundImage: Image.gif;Position: 0, 0;Width: 320;Height: 480;}Button{BackgroundImage: Button.gif;Position: 49, 80;Width: 216;Height: 71;}Button{BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;Transition: View2;Position: 65, 217;Width: 188;Height: 134;}Label{Position: 106, 91;Width: 96;Height: 34;Text: "Button";FontSize: 32;Color: 0.12549, 0.298039, 0.364706, 1;}';

var ret = {};

while(group = re.exec(content)) {
    var k = group[1],
        v = group[2];

    ret[k] = ret[k] ? ret[k].substring(0, ret[k].length - 1) + v.substring(1, v.length) : v;
}


// output
console.log(ret);   // => {'Button': '{xxx}', 'Image': '{xxxx}', 'Label': '{xxxx}'}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. You can parse it to JSON if you want key value targeting whatsoever. But I think this is not valid JSON.

```
var content='Image{BackgroundImage: Image.gif;Position: 0, 0;Width: 320;Height: 480;}' +
'Button{BackgroundImage: Button.gif;Position: 49, 80;Width: 216;Height: 71;}' +
'Button2{BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;Transition: View2;Position: 65, 217;Width: 188;Height: 134;}' +
'Label{Position: 106, 91;Width: 96;Height: 34;Text: "Button";FontSize: 32;Color: 0.12549, 0.298039, 0.364706, 1;}';

// add colons after the keys
content = content.replace(/([\w]+){/g, '"$1":{');

// wrap all {} in quotes
content = content.replace(/({[^}]+})/g, '"$1",');

// remove trailing comma
content = content.slice(0, -1);

content = '{"Controls": [{' + content + '}]}';

console.log(content);
```